# Chrome extension breaks HTTPS on all URLS being loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Chrome extension breaks HTTPS on all URLS being loaded.

Any suggestions on where to start looking for the cause?

The status of the connection as given by Chrome is:

> Your connection to this site is private, but someone on the network might be able to change the look of the page.
>   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2gHz.png)

Disabling the extension resolves HTTPS.

Comment: what is the chrome extension/what does it do? sample code would be helpful

Comment: This only means that a ressource loaded by the page was not secured. Can be anything... An image, a script.. Called using an url begining with "http://" instead of "https://". Check your console (hit [F12] on your keyboard)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thanks for the suggestion. I've verified that without the extension, the same pages successfully load with HTTPS.

Comment: So would my comment be a good answer enought for me to submit and close this question ?

Comment: @NoamHacker the extension lets the user take the current page and add it as a post to a platform, with comments. I don't know which code is causing this but I suspect the permissions may have something to do with it.

Comment: @Manil Chowdhury: The only thing is that the «extention» is hosted on a non-https adress. If you can dowload it and host it by yourself on your server, this will fix your SSL problem.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the extention script and place it on your server.
So you can access it without refering to a `<script src="http://...>`.

But a `<script src="/path/to/this/js/on/your/server" ...>`.

The problem isn't the extention itself, but it's location.